# 2007 Dodge Caliber Won't Start, Cranking Sounds Odd

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, dodge, caliber

We've got a 2007 Dodge Caliber that suddenly won't turn over. I thought it was the battery, measured the voltage with a multimeter at 11.7v and replaced it but the problem persists. It doesn't seem to "crank" in the normal way - I've uploaded a video showing the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rmZ1y3w2j8

Would love any ideas on what this could be?

Comment: Have you scanned for any codes? I'm not hearing it even wanting to start.

Comment: I ordered a code reader thats coming today, I'll report back with the results!

Comment: I just scanned the codes on the car and we get P0522, p0522 Pd and P0455 Pd. Sounds like there may not be enough oil?

Comment: P0522 is saying the oil pressure sensor is not detecting oil pressure. P0455 is stating you have a large leak in the EVAP system, meaning your fuel tank is not sealing correctly. I'm not sure what the "Pd" means, though I believe it might mean a "permanent" item, especially since there are two codes you show for P0522. You might try clearing the codes and see if they come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow up on the solution for this - we took the car in and apparently when we swapped out the battery (the old one read less than 12v on the multimeter) the car went into "security mode?" Once the computer was reset everything works normally.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what the issue ended up being.